# F# and Mono Cecil How to work with it?

Tags: c#, f#, mono

I am working on an obfuscation mechanism using F#.

I wrote the same thing using C# before a few months as follows:

```cs
public void testobfusc(string file)
{
    AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file);
    ModuleDefinition module = assembly.MainModule;
    foreach (TypeDefinition type in module.Types)
    {
        type.Name = "Yaobfuscatethis"; // Maybe I should use random function here
     }
 }
```

Now, I'm trying to write the same thing in F#. First, I reference `Mono.Cecil` and then write:

```
open Mono.Cecil

let obfus(file:string)=
    use asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file)
    let ModuleDefinition = asm.MainModule
    TypeDefinition(asm.MainModule.Types)
    t.Name = ""
```

.. but this code does not work.

Comment: I think your question accidentally got obfuscated...

Comment: @galeda Talking about professional StackOverflow style, your question was really poorly written. I tried to de-obfuscate it a bit, but feel free to correct it if my crystal ball did not work correctly.

Comment: I would say,,, Ok was my fault maybe in future i should ask the question differently. but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translated (not tested):

```ml
let testobfusc (file:string) = 
    let assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file)
    let ``module`` = assembly.MainModule
    ``module``.Types |> Seq.iter (fun t -> t.Name <- "Yaobfuscatethis")
```